# Excel VBA UserForm (Activate Sheet by listbox selection)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to great a function that show a ListBox that is filled with all the shapes on every worksheet. I have no problem with that. But I would like it when a shape is selected that the sheet, and shape is activate.

```
//Module(Custom)
Public Function getShape(Target As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet   
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim main As MainForm
    Set main = New MainForm
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each sh In ws.shapes
            main.AddShape sh, ws
        Next sh
    Next ws
    main.Show
End Function

//For MainForm
Dim shape_collection As Collection
Dim sheet_collection As Collection
Dim cnt As Integer

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set ws = sheet_collection.item(ListBox1.ListIndex + 1)
    Set sh = shape_collection.item(ListBox1.ListIndex + 1)
    Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate
    Worksheets(ws.Name).Select
    Worksheets(ws.Name).Visible = True
    sh.Select
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set shape_collection = New Collection
    Set sheet_collection = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub AddShape(sh As Shape, ws As Worksheet)
    ListBox1.AddItem (sh.Name)
    shape_collection.Add sh
    sheet_collection.Add ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry you are saying you want to open a sheet using a form list box and then also activate a shape in the same sheet? Or do you want to add a shape object to the sheet?

Comment: I want when they select the shape in the listbox the sheet becomes visible that the shape is on and the shape is selected.I don't need to create any shapes dynamically. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: I suggest in your AddShape function u also make a table like shape index, sheetname, shape name. shape index is the index of the sape in the listbox. this way when a shape is clicked in the listbox, u can look back in this table for the sheet and shapename. Activate that sheet ans select the shape.